# Creating an observable that emits values periodically (error: observer.timer is not a function)

Tags: rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

I have an object that looks like this: `[{ timestamp: object }]`
The `timestamp` is created `timestamp = Date.now();`

Now, I am looking for a way to create an `Observable` that emits the objects in the real sequence, i.e. when the time between entries is 200ms then it needs to wait 200ms, if it's 2.5 seconds then it needs to wait 2500ms.

I get the difference by subtracting the two adjacent index values from each other.

My code is here:

```
startReplay() {
  this.recordingRunning = true;
  const replayValues = this.recordedListeningValues;
  this.formObservable = Observable.create(function(observer) {
    let lastTs;
    Object.keys(replayValues).forEach(function(key) {
        observer.timer(Math.floor((Number(key) - lastTs) / 1000)).next(key, lastTs);
        lastTs = Number(key);
    });
  });
  var source = this.formObservable.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
}
```

It throws the error: `observer.timer is not a function`

At the moment, I am only trying to `log` the differences between the timestamps in seconds. Now, I want to emit it in the differences between the two timestamps.

Comment: `onNext` was used in RxJS 4, in RxJS 5 call `next` instead.

Comment: thanks a lot that solves one problem and it works.

Comment: `Observable.interval` - I guess this is used to create an observable emit periodically.

Comment: Yeah, I think I wouldn't be able to do this using timer, would I?

Comment: `Observable.timer` not `observer.timer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [delayWhen](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/delaywhen.html) operator.  But you need to know the timestamp of the start of the recording so that you can calculate the time of each event relative to the start of the recording

```
const startOfRecording = ??? // Date.now() when recording started
const recordedValues = ???

// each time someone subscribes to this observable
// the recorded events will play back in "real time"
this.formObservable = Observable
    .from(Object.keys(replayValues))
    .delayWhen(key => Observable.timer(key - startOfRecording))
    .map(key => replayValues[key]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try tomorrow and report back. This looks promising.

Comment: Thank you, that works! How can I determine what the Observable does `onComplete`? I knew how to do it on `Observer`.

Comment: Add a .finally(() => console.log("done")) to the end